# Is it normal to not see any new schemas, databases, or tables for a newly hooked up RDBMS for a Dockerized Keycloak server?

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, jdbc, keycloak

The use case is me trying to connect the Dockerized version of Keycloak with an external native PostgreSQL instance like this:

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KC_DB=postgres
# Install custom providers
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore

ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:'jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak'
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=postgres
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=1997
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

***Bash Commands***

```bash
sudo docker build . -t prebuilt_keycloak &&
sudo docker run --network="host" --name optimized_keycloak -p 8443:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me prebuilt_keycloak start --optimized
```

The web dashboard works fine, and any data entered into it seems to persist between container restarts.
JDBC gave some complaints initially, but seemed to finally work after some minor tweaks.

Still nothing when I check with something like `\l` in `psql`.

Is this normal behavior? Am I missing something? Or is there some manual setup required on the database that I missed?

Comment: The psql command `\l` does not list schema, tables, etc it lists databases only. As far as not new database(s) they would be listed only if you created them. Since you did not mention any one seems like you haven not created one.

Comment: @Belayer Yeah, that's why I said it, and commands like it. The most recent reference material made it seem like Keycloak's DB creation was automatic (saw some SQL setup code for older versions). Either way, it seems like I've misunderstood how Keycloak persists data, since that still works (I think?).